# Import Tally Data into Openerp

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I am working on module for which i am using tally_integrator module of openerp. after successfull installation when i am trying to import tally data i am getting following error

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 180, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(controller, self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1052, in call_button
    action = self.call_common(req, model, method, args, domain_id, context_id)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 996, in call_common
    return self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1010, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/openerplib/main.py", line 250, in proxy
    args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/openerplib/main.py", line 117, in proxy
    result = self.connector.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 608, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.exception_to_unicode(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 593, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 360, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 586, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 186, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 129, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 195, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 183, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/tally_integrator/wizard/tally_connection.py", line 142, in tally_main
    _processData(s)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/tally_integrator/wizard/tally_connection.py", line 124, in _processData
    f = self.createTempFile(s)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/tally_integrator/wizard/tally_connection.py", line 106, in createTempFile
    f = open('temp.xml','w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'temp.xml'
```

Please let me know what is that error i have changed the permission of following directory
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp

but i am still getting this error. Please help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have done the openerp installation by the book,  for any kind of permission denied errors on in the form of:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/etl'
```

The general solution according to me is:

```
cd /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
chown -R openerp: openerp
```

The chown command is designed to change the ownership of the openerp folder under `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7` to the user `openerp`.  That is the user under which your openerp-server process should be running.

I have been working on openerp for about 2 days now.  I am not an expert yet.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of stating the obvious, you don't have write permissions for that location.  As there is no path, I presume it will be opened in your current working directory.  Do a `ps -ef` to get your PID and then run `ls -ld /proc/PID/cwd` - this will show you the current working directory of the process and then check the write bits and user/group on the directory.

Comment: I already set the permission using "chmod -R 777 openerp" command. But i still unable to get data from tally.

Comment: Prashant, that is my point.  I don't believe the file is being created in that location so you need to figure out just where the file is being created.  BTW be very careful doing recursive chmod 777 on a linux system, you can break stuff doing that.